# What is being logged in iptables with these entries?

Tags: logging, routes, firewall, iptables

I have a server behind a hardware firewall supplied by the phone company.  I'm logging these entries with iptables.  Do these entries imply that the connection attempts from the SRC= addresses are making it through the firewall so that they can connect to the server?  The server IP is 192.168.0.250.

```
Feb  6 04:00:56 avserver2 kernel: [14712601.165416] DROP-0-250: IN=eth0 OUT= SRC=15.161.233.60 DST=192.168.0.250 LEN=84 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=32 ID=0 PROTO=ICMP TYPE=8 CODE=0 ID=7 SEQ=5033 
Feb  6 04:00:57 avserver2 kernel: [14712601.895472] DROP-0-250: IN=eth0 OUT= SRC=27.221.18.26 DST=192.168.0.250 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=51 ID=38799 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=57348 DPT=22 WINDOW=14600 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 
Feb  6 04:00:58 avserver2 kernel: [14712602.728191] DROP-0-250: IN=eth0 OUT= SRC=15.161.246.141 DST=192.168.0.250 LEN=84 TOS=0x08 PREC=0x20 TTL=30 ID=0 PROTO=ICMP TYPE=8 CODE=0 ID=21 SEQ=12199
```

Comment: I asked this at Super User, so please disregard if Stack Overflow was in appropriate for the question.

Answer (score 0):

What I see here is a ping echo request from 15.161.233.60 and 15.161.246.141 to your server.
And an ssh connection request (SYN) from 27.221.18.26 to your server.

So I'm guessing your hw firewall is letting these requests go through, but there are no replies in kernel logs.

Comment: Thanks - it appears that the firewall is allowing these connections, and it should not if it's behind a properly configured firewall.